# break, if following string is <div>

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find string after `#` , I have a problem if `#a` or `#a&nbsp;<div>..`
are both working to return `a`, but if `#a<div>..` will return `a<div>`.

how to avoid if following string is `<div>` or `<br>` or `<p>` than just break, 
e.g
`#a<div>bc` - `a`

https://regex101.com/r/xD1vN0/1

```
var re = /#([^#\s]*)/g;
```

Comment: You mea `/#([^<#\s]*)/g`? Or should it be really `<div>`, a literal? Like, if you have `#a<door>`, it would be accepted?

Comment: yes I want only <div>, <br>, <p>

Comment: Try [`#((?:(?!<(?:div|br|p)>)[^#\s])*)`](https://regex101.com/r/xI2wY9/3)

Comment: do you want to leave a answer

Comment: I posted with an explanation.

Comment: Don't use regex for getting html tags' attributes and contents. Use a parser and parse the html!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for explanation

Comment: @Vohuman why can't use regex?? I was using https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio parse html content then find #tag but the input string is from contenteditable element so it will generate string like `#a<div>bc</div> #d` (only div, br, p html tag I guess) and after parse by cheerio text method `#abc #d`.  or you have some example solution?? I want to doing on server side nodejs javascript, don't wanna on client side

Comment: base on @Vohuman comment,  I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105/why-its-not-possible-to-use-regex-to-parse-html-xml-a-formal-explanation-in-la, but I think in this case string will not contain whole html tags only some generate from contenteditable element, so thats why I use regex doing this.  any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a regex with a [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
/#((?:(?!<(?:div|br|p)>)[^#\s])*)/g
```

The `(?:(?!<(?:div|br|p)>)[^#\s])*` is a tempered greedy token that matches any character other than `#` and whitespace that do not start a sequence of either `<div>`, `<br>`, or `<p>`.

JS demo:

```js
var re = /#((?:(?!<(?:div|br|p)>)[^#\s])*)/g; 
var str = `#a<div>
#b<br>
#c<p>
#d<hi>`;
var res = [];
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    res.push(m[1]);
}
document.body.innerHTML = "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res.map(x => x.replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/</g,"&gt;")), 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern to break if a `<` is reached

```
var re = /#([^#\s^<]*)/g;
```